# Open a Command in a New Instance of Various Terminal Emulators

Tags: bash, terminal

**I am trying to open a terminal emulator while simultaneously passing a compound command to it.  What are commands for doing this (two versions: where the terminal stays open after completing or where it closes)?**

---

For example, for the `xterm` terminal emulator, the command `xterm -e "ls; sleep 3"` makes a new `xterm` GUI window, lists the current directory, waits for 3 seconds, and then closes the window.

I am specifically interested in invocations for `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `lxterminal`, `rxvt`, `terminator`, `xfce4-terminal`, and `xterm`, as well as Windows's `cmd`.

---

Here are some example usages of what I've figured out myself so far:

```
Emulator        |  Invocation (Exiting)              |  Invocation (Persistent)           |
----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
cmd             |  start CMD /C "DATE /T & TIME /T"  |  start CMD /K "DATE /T & TIME /T"  |
gnome-terminal  |  ???                               |  ???                               |
konsole         |  ???                               |  ???                               |
lxterminal      |  ???                               |  ???                               |
rxvt            |  ???                               |  ???                               |
terminator      |  ???                               |  ???                               |
xfce4-terminal  |  ???                               |  ???                               |
xterm           |  xterm -e "ls; sleep 3"            |  xterm -e "ls; sleep 3; bash"      |
```

Can anyone help me fill in more?  Partial answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from `cmd`, those all are X terminal emulators, and most provide some variation of xterm's `-e` option.  Where they differ lies in whether they require the option value to be quoted.

Aside from shell limitations, xterm uses *all* of the tokens past `-e` as part of the command.  They need not be quoted as shown (which makes one token).  rxvt follows that behavior (see [documentation](http://www.rxvt.org/manual.html)).

There are also subtle differences, according to how the command is passed to the shell; xterm documents some of that in the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) (look for "shell" and "filter") while none of the others provide that level of detail.  You can only find *those* by reading the source code or testing.

According to [documentation](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html), konsole also follows the `-e` behavior of xterm (the prevailing convention).

gnome-terminal differs from the convention (see [documentation](http://www.fifi.org/doc/gnome-terminal/html/gnome-terminal/C/options.html)):

> `--command` *CMD*`, -e` *CMD*
>
> Runs the *CMD* command at startup time.
>
> `--execute` *CMD* *ARGS*`, -x` *CMD* *ARGS*
>
> Executes the command *CMD* with its arguments *ARGS* on startup. No arguments beyond this one will be processed by the terminal. This behaviour mimics the xterm -e behaviour.

That is, its `-e` option expects a single token.  Rather than amend it to provide compatibility, its developers chose to provide *similar* functionality with a different option name.

The others use almost all of the same code as gnome-terminal, and depending on the extent of sharing, may implement `-e` like the others, or just copy from gnome-terminal:

[lxterminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html)

> `-e` *STRING* `--command=`*STRING*`--command`*STRING*
>
> This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments)
> to be run in the terminal. Except in the --command= form, this must
> be the last option on the command line.

terminator [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator) matches gnome-terminal

xfce4-terminal [documentation](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/command-line) matches lxterminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main problem I had was that for most terminal emulators, the command argument is expected to be a single item (i.e., there is no shell-style parsing).  For example

```
rxvt -e "ls; sleep 3"
```

fails, even though this is the same way `xterm` was invoked.

If you try to unquote it, that won't work either.  For example:

```
rxvt -e ls; sleep 3
```

is parsed and executed separately, as two commands:

```
rxvt -e ls
sleep 3
```

---

Using a trick I found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/running-multiple-commands-in-konsole-645705/#post3168707), you can invoke the terminal emulator to run `bash`, and then pass commands to `bash`'s interpreter instead of the emulator's.  This both solves the problem and has more consistent behavior, since in all cases it is `bash` that is parsing the main command string.

Using a trick I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23483292/688624), you can invoke `bash` for `xterm`, thus leaving a shell open and thereby producing the persistent variant:

```
rxvt -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3;bash"
```

This works for `konsole`, `lxterminal`, and `terminator` too (`terminator` at least also supports `-x` it seems).  However, if you think about it (or use `gnome-terminal`'s equivalent `-x` and then observe the warning when you try to close the window), you realize that the terminal is running `bash`, and that that `bash` is running `bash`.  Instead, you want to *replace* the `bash`-that's-going-to-terminate with a `bash`-that-won't:

```
rxvt -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"
```

This can be seen in the wild [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466566/688624).

Note [an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303477/688624) is `xterm`'s `-hold` option, which has equivalents on some other terminals (e.g. `konsole`'s `--hold`).  The hold option prevents the terminal emulator from closing, but doesn't give you interactivity back.  This wasn't really what I was looking for, but I have listed it below for completeness.

Here's the table (different format since these commands are getting longer).  I have also added `urxvt`.  All invocations have been tested:

```
Emulator       | Command Type        | Invocation                                      
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
cmd            | exiting             | start CMD /C "DATE /T & TIME /T"                
               | persistent          | ???                                             
               | persistent (inter.) | start CMD /K "DATE /T & TIME /T"                
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
gnome-terminal | exiting             | gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3"          
               | persistent          | ???                                             
               | persistent (inter.) | gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
konsole        | exiting             | konsole -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3"                 
               | persistent          | konsole --hold -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3"          
               | persistent (inter.) | konsole -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"       
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
lxterminal     | exiting             | lxterminal -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3"              
               | persistent          | ???                                             
               | persistent (inter.) | lxterminal -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"    
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
rxvt           | exiting             | rxvt -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3"                    
               | persistent          | ???                                             
               | persistent (inter.) | rxvt -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"          
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
terminator     | exiting             | terminator -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3"              
               | persistent          | ???                                             
               | persistent (inter.) | terminator -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"    
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
urxvt          | exiting             | urxvt -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3"                   
               | persistent          | urxvt -hold -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3"             
               | persistent (inter.) | urxvt -e bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"         
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
xfce4-terminal | exiting             | xfce4-terminal -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3"          
               | persistent          | xfce4-terminal --hold -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3"   
               | persistent (inter.) | xfce4-terminal -x bash -c "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"
---------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------
xterm          | exiting             | xterm -e "ls;sleep 3"                           
               | persistent          | xterm -hold -e "ls; sleep 3"                    
               | persistent (inter.) | xterm -e "ls;sleep 3;exec bash"
```

The remaining question marks I do not think are possible.

Feel free to edit this table with any new terminals, new invocations, or corrections.